# Declare Code as JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, joomla, mootools

I have mootools and jquery installed (Joomla) for various reasons, and I think my jquery code is trying to run through mootools because I keep getting a bunch of garbage errors with `$.getJSON`. Is there something I can wrap around my Jquery code that I don't have this kind of cross-framework conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use noConflict():

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

You can replace $ with any variable you want:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

If you read the doc, you can use noConflict and still use $ within a $.ready() call, and use $ for mootools outside of the ready call.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then try replace the `$` with `jQuery`

or alternatively just `jQuery.noConflict();` and keep using `$`

Check [this](http://www.alltogetherasawhole.org/profiles/blogs/preventing-jquery-and-mootools)

Comment: replace all my `$` with `Jquery`!?